# Is there any file that is called only on login where i set a global variable and that should be used in all controller and views in laravel

Tags: laravel

I am trying to create a global variable which will be updated when the login is performed. I need to access that global variable in all the controller and views.

Comment: Under your login functionality create a session variable and save any value in it and that session will be available in entire application

Answer (score 1):

You may use the global session helper to create a global variable. When you login, define the session in your LoginController like that:

```
session(['key' => 'value']);
```

To retrieve the data you must:

```
$value = session('key');
```

Reference: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/session#introduction